# C# bool return class

Tags: c#

I started to code today, and I have a question about bool class which I cannot solve. I want to create a new bool, that after comparison the class will return a bool.
this is the error I get:

> 'Pictureori' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments

As I said, started coding just today so help is appreciated!!

```
public class Pictureori
{
  public bool tog(int x, int y)
  {
    int picwih = x;
    int pichight = y;

    if (picwih > pichight)
    {
       return true;
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
  }

  class Program
  {
     public static void Main(string[] args)
     {
          Console.WriteLine("Please enter picture size");
          bool Ortintation = new Pictureori(15,26);

     }
  }
```

Comment: Pictureori has no constructor (only the default with 0 parameters), so you can't do `new Pictureori(15, 26)`.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
bool Ortintation = new Pictureori().tog(15,26);
```

Or:

```
Pictureori newObj = new Pictureori();
bool Ortintation = newObj.tog(15,26);
```

First line creates an `Instance` of the class, the second line is a `method` call.

Or, because you class doesn't have any data you could define your method as static, In that case you don't need to instance new object.

```
public static bool tog(int x, int y)
...
bool Ortintation =  Pictureori.tog(15,26);
```

Comment: Or: Change `tog` to `Pictureori`.